# Maven lastUpdated timestamps in maven-metadata.xml have been set to the future

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

I am using Maven 3.9.1 on Windows 10. I also use Eclipse EE 2023-03, which contains m2e (Eclipse's support for Maven). I am checking a POM for plugin version updates using the [Versions Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/), but many aren't showing up even though another person sees updates available in Maven Central when checking against the same POM. (See [Issue #959](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/issues/959).) After some investigation it appears that the `<lastUpdated>` values in `maven-metadata.xml` in my local repository have been set to the future. I can try to override them, but first I am trying to find out how it happened so that I can prevent it from happening again.

I ran the following update to get Maven debug information:

```bash
mvn -X versions:display-plugin-updates
```

Here is part of my result:

```
…
[DEBUG] Checking com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin for updates newer than 2.1.3
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date
[DEBUG] [com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin].version=2.1.3
[DEBUG] [com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin].artifactVersion=2.1.2
[DEBUG] [com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin].effectiveVersion=2.1.3
[DEBUG] [com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin].specified=true
…
```

However another person ran this output, and it indicated the following update (among others which also don't show up for me):

> `com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin  2.1.3 -> 2.4.1`

It looks like on my machine Maven isn't seeing that `com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:2.1.3` needed updating. This debug information seems to be saying that it can't find `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\akathist\maven\plugins\launch4j\launch4j-maven-plugin\maven-metadata.xml`. And in fact that file does *not* exist! Instead I have `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\akathist\maven\plugins\launch4j\launch4j-maven-plugin\maven-metadata-central.xml`. (It's not clear to me what the difference is, and I can't find information about this online.)

But the more ominous line is this one:

> `[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date`

The `maven-metadata-central.xml` file contains `<lastUpdated>20210818055556</lastUpdated>`, and an [online Linux epoch timestamp converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) tells me that **this date is Saturday, June 16, 2610 12:07:35.556 PM**!

Here is more information on files inside `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\akathist\maven\plugins\launch4j\launch4j-maven-plugin\`:

- The checksum in `maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1` matches the SHA-1 hash of `maven-metadata-central.xml`. But the file timestamp on `maven-metadata-central.xml` is almost a month later (2022-10-02) than that of `maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1` (2022-09-08).
- The `<lastUpdated>20210818055556</lastUpdated>` inside `maven-metadata-central.xml`, as mentioned above, indicates 2610-06-16.
- The `resolver-status.properties` file timestamp is identical to that of `maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1`, so they were apparently modified at the same time. The comments inside `resolver-status.properties` also say it was modified on 2022-09-08, and the `central.maven-metadata-central.xml.lastUpdated=1662676475074` inside the file also seems to say that Maven Central was checked on that date.

Interestingly 2022-09-08 is when I released v0.8.10 of this POM to Maven Central. As part of doing that, I used `versions:use-releases`, `versions:set`, and `versions:display-dependency-updates`; along with the Nexus Staging Maven Plugin of course. Since the checksum of `maven-metadata-central.xml` matches that in `maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1`, which was updated on 2022-09-08, it seems likely that the incorrect `<lastUpdated>20210818055556</lastUpdated>` was set on 2022-09-08.

Has anyone heard of what plugin or version of Maven or Eclipse m2e version or any bug or circumstances that might have resulted in setting `<lastUpdated>` to a date in the future for metadata in the `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\` tree?

Comment: So you say `<lastUpdated>20210818055556</lastUpdated>` means 2610-06-16, not 2021-08-18, right? [Is the versions-maven-plugin you are using from 2611](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/versions-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml) or an older one? ;)

Comment: @howlger thank you for setting me straight on my mistaken assumption in this question. I wonder if you have any insight into https://stackoverflow.com/q/76307809 . No one else seems to have a clue what is causing this, and in fact no one seems to know what particular timestamp Maven Artifact Resolver uses to determine if the cache is stale. Maybe your expertise in this area can shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Maven internals here and also have no guess at what is going wrong here. At your new question, Maven developer [_khmarbaise_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) has commented. He is the expert here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is based on the **false assumption** that in `maven-metadata.xml` the `<lastUpdated>` values are **Linux epoch timestamps**.

In fact, the **`<lastUpdated>`** values are given as **`yyyyMMddHHmmss`** timestamps.

For example, you can see this in the [`maven-metadata.xml` file of the *Versions Maven Plugin*](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/versions-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml) currently contains `<lastUpdated>20230221231058</lastUpdated>` as its latest version [2.15.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/versions-maven-plugin/2.15.0) has been released in February 2023.

Comment: Oh, yes, I was making that assumption. Thank you very much for setting me straight! But with that new understanding, now I have no idea why Versions Maven Plugin on my machine is not seeing recent versions available from Maven Central; see [Versions Maven Plugin Issue #959](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/issues/959). Now I'm back to square one.

Comment: I've opened up a new question without the erroneous assumption about the timestamp format. Any information there to help my investigation would be appreciated. [Maven Artifact Resolver not seeing latest plugins on Maven Central on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76307809)